# How can I fix my module system for my coding language?

Tags: python

I am making a coding language with Python. I am working on a module system for custom made modules.
The full code is at https://repl.it/@UCYT5040/koolCode and `interp.py` but the issue I am having is with this code:

```py
for i in keywords:
    keyword = i.lower()
    if keyword == "print":
        for i1 in quotes:
            print(i1)
    elif keyword == "add":
        for i1 in quotes:
            quote = i1.lower()
            if quote == "python":
                modulesInfo["python"] = {"runLang":"python","runpy":"{quote}"}
                modules.append("python")
            else:
                print("koolCode WARN: custom modules not supported/module not found.")
    else:
        for i1 in modules:
            if modulesInfo[i1]["runLang"] == "python":
                try:
                    eval("f\"" + modulesInfo[i1][keyword] + "\"")
                except KeyError:
                    print(f"koolCode ERROR: Module")
```

I get this error:

```
Welcome to koolCode console.
Would you like to open a file? y/n
n
A file will not be opened. Type any commands below.
koolCode>add "python"
['add'] ['python']
koolCode>runpy "help()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    noFile()
  File "main.py", line 3, in noFile
    runString(input("koolCode>"))
  File "/home/runner/koolCode/interp.py", line 46, in runString
    eval("f\"" + modulesInfo[i1][keyword] + "\"")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'quote' is not defined
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what is there in quotes?

Comment: I think that `modulesInfo[i1][keyword]` result into `"{quote}"`and when you make into a f-string and evaluate it with eval cause the error, and the reason is that in this branch of your if-elif-else `quote` is not defined because you didn't pass for the `"add"` case before or never do any iteration in that case because `quotes` is empty

Comment: Is the problem simply that in this line: `modulesInfo["python"] = {"runLang":"python","runpy":"{quote}"}` you expect `"{quote}"` to be replaced with the value of the `quote` variable?  That isn't going to happen because `"{quote}"` isn't an f-string.  So maybe you want to add an 'f' to the front of that string literal?

Comment: I put it in an f string as you can see here `eval("f\"" + modulesInfo[i1][keyword] + "\"")`